# iloc using scikit learn random forest classifier

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a random forest classifier to determine the 'type' of an object based on different attributes. I am having trouble understanding `iloc` and separating the predictors from the classification. If the 50th column is the 'type' column, I am wondering why the `iloc` (commented out) line does not work, but the line `y = dataset["type"]` does. I have attached the code below. Thank you!

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:50].values
y = dataset["type"]
#y = dataset.iloc[:,50].values
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that the first column in your dataframe is named "0" and the following columns are named consequently. Like the result of the following lines

```
last_col=50
tab=pd.DataFrame([[x for x in range(last_col)] for c in range(10)])
```

now, please try `tab.iloc[:,0:50]` - it will work because you used slice to select columns indexes. 
But if you try `tab.iloc[:,50]` - it will not work, because there is no column with index 50.

Slicing and selecting column by its index is just a bit different. From pandas documentation:
**.iloc[] is primarily integer position based (from 0 to length-1 of the axis)**

I hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for your help!